# Best practice to work with image upload in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

The application need to allow user to upload an passport photo so that admin can verify the user.

This tutorial http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/file-upload-in-aspnet5-mvc6 explains about file upload in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6.

However, the file is uploaded to a folder in project folder.
Is is the best practice? Is there any problem if there is thousands of users ?
Should I use Azure storage? 
Will the code more complicated if I use Azure storage?
Do you have any 
recommendation?

Comment: Your code should depend upon IFileService which can FileSystemIFileService or AzureFileService or anyother implementation which you can replace anytime via DI :)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you upload to the file through your WebAPI, the web server that running under IIS had only access to folder underneath it's virtual root. If you want to store the file somewhere else, you could use \servername\urpath, provided that ur path is shared and grant write access to "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" or other AppPool if you use a different one.